# An algorithm for efficiently replacing an array elements with groups

Tags: python, algorithm

There are N elements, each element has its own cost. And there are M groups. Each group includes several indices of elements from the array and has its own cost.

input for example

```
6
100 5
200 5
300 5
400 5
500 5
600 3
2
4 6
100 200 300 700
3 5
300 400 500
```

The first number N is the number of elements. The next N lines contain the index and cost of a particular item. Then comes the number M (number of groups). After it comes 2*M lines . These lines contain the number of elements in the group, the cost of the group itself, and the indices of the elements.

I want to find the minimum cost for which can purchase all N items.

In the example, it is most advantageous to take both groups and purchase an element with the number 600 separately. The answer is 14. (6+5+3)

Here is my solution

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

N = int(input())
dct = {}
groups = PriorityQueue()

for i in range(N):
    a,c = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    dct[a] = c 

M = int(input())


for i in range(M): 
    k,c = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    s = 0
    tmp = []
    for j in input().split():
        j_=int(j)
        if j_ in dct:
            s+=dct[j_]
            tmp.append(j_)
    d = c-s
    if d<0:
        groups.put([d, c, tmp])  

s = 0
while not groups.empty():
    #print(dct)
    #for i in groups.queue:
    #    print(i)
    g = groups.get()
    if g[0]>0:
        break
    #print('G',g)
    #print('-------')
    for i in g[2]:
        if i in dct:
            del(dct[i])
    s += g[1]
    groups_ = PriorityQueue()
    for i in range(len(groups.queue)):
            g_ = groups.get()
            s_ = 0
            tmp_ = []
            for i in g_[2]:
                if i in dct:
                    s_+=dct[i]
                    tmp_.append(i)
            d = g_[1]-s_
            groups_.put([d, g_[1], tmp_])
    groups = groups_ 

for i in dct:
    s+=dct[i]

print(s)
```

But it is not completely true.

For example, for such a test, it gives an answer of 162. But the correct answer is 160. It is most beneficial to take only the first and second groups and take an element with index 0 separately.

```
20
0 24
1 32
2 33
3 57
4 57
5 50
6 50
7 41
8 2
9 73
10 81
11 73
12 55
13 3
14 54
15 43
16 98
17 8
18 41
19 97
5
17 61
17 9 11 15 1 13 14 7 20 2 3 16 12 5 8 4 6
13 75
20 15 5 9 10 11 7 8 18 2 4 19 16
10 96
3 9 4 18 11 6 8 5 2 14
9 92
18 1 6 9 19 8 4 16 10
19 77
14 17 18 3 2 4 7 6 8 9 10 20 13 12 15 19 1 16 5
```

I also tried brute-force search, but such a solution would be too slow

```
from itertools import combinations

N = int(input())
dct = {}

s = 0
for i in range(N):
    a,c = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    dct[a] = c
    s += c
m = s

M = int(input())

groups = []
for i in range(M):
    k,c = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
    s = 0
    tmp = []
    for j in input().split():
        j_=int(j)
        if j_ in dct:
            s+=dct[j_]
            tmp.append(j_)
    groups.append( [c, tmp] )

for u in range(1,M+1):
    for i in list(combinations(groups, u)): 
        s = 0
        tmp = dct.copy()
        for j in i:
            s += j[0]
            for t in j[1]:
                if t in tmp:
                    del(tmp[t])
        for j in tmp:
            s += tmp[j] 
        #print(i,s)
        if s < m:
            m = s  
print(m)
```

I think that this problem is solved with the help of dynamic programming. Perhaps this is some variation of the typical Knapsack problem. Tell me which algorithm is better to use.

Comment: I'd say dynamic programming has a good shot of working, but probably the numbers `N` and `M` have to be bounded for an efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

The so-called [set cover problem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Set_cover_problem)(which is NP-Hard) seems like a special case of your problem. Therefore, I am afraid there is no efficient algorithm that solves it.

Comment: I am using this particular algorithm. You can see my code. But why does it decide incorrectly for the test I have indicated?

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, this is a hard problem for which no "efficient" algorithm exists.

You can approach this as a graph problem, where the nodes of the graph are all possible combinations of groups (where each element on its own is also a group). Two nodes *u* and *v* are connected with a directed edge when there is a group *g* such that the union of the keys in *u* and in *g*, corresponds to the set of keys in *v*.

Then perform a Dijkstra search in this graph, starting from the node that represents the state where no groups are selected at all (cost 0, no keys). This search will minimise the cost, and you can use the extra optimisation that a group *g* is never considered twice in the same path. As soon as a state (node) is visited that covers all the keys, you can exit the algorithm -- typical for the Dijkstra algorithm -- as this represents the minimal cost to cover all the keys.

Such an algorithm is still quite costly, as at each addition of an edge to a path, a union of keys must be calculated. And,... quite some memory is needed to keep all states in the heap.

Here is a potential implementation:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
import heapq

# Some named tuple types, to make the code more readable
Group = namedtuple("Group", "cost numtodo keys")
Node = namedtuple("Node", "cost numtodo keys nextgroupid")

def collectinput():
    inputNumbers = lambda: [int(j) for j in input().split()]

    groups = []
    keys = []

    N, = inputNumbers()
    for i in range(N):
        key, cost = inputNumbers()
        keys.append(key)
        # Consider these atomic keys also as groups (with one key)
        # The middle element of this tuple may seem superficial, but it improves sorting
        groups.append(Group(cost, N-1, [key]))
    keys = set(keys)

    M, = inputNumbers()
    for i in range(M):
        cost = inputNumbers()[-1]
        groupkeys = [key for key in inputNumbers() if key in keys]
        groups.append(Group(cost, N-len(groupkeys), groupkeys))

    return keys, groups


def solve(keys, groups):
    N = len(keys)
    groups.sort() # sort by cost, if equal, by number of keys left 

    # The starting node of the graph search
    heap = [Node(0, N, [], 0)]

    while len(heap):
        node = heapq.heappop(heap)
        if node.numtodo == 0:
            return node.cost
        for i in range(node.nextgroupid, len(groups)):
            group = groups[i]
            unionkeys = list(set(node.keys + group.keys))
            if len(unionkeys) > len(node.keys):
                heapq.heappush(heap, Node(node.cost + group.cost, N-len(unionkeys), unionkeys, i+1))

# Main
keys, groups = collectinput()
cost = solve(keys, groups)
print("solution: {}".format(cost))
```

This outputs 160 for the second problem you posted.

Comment: Such a solution is not much better than brute force search.

Comment: I think that the problem is solved by a greedy algorithm.